# What's the better practice for organization API calls with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, structure

What's the better practice / convenient implementation for organization API calls with redux? I

I have

- some data from API which I store in redux. Also I store token for API
  in redux
- data from API which I do not need to store in redux
- API calls that require a token
- API calls that NOT require a token
- And API calls that not that require a token and I do not need store response in redux

So the main question is. Should I use actions for API calls even if I do not need to store response in redux, but for **some** of them I need token from redux?

Or use actions with API only for those which response I will store in redux.
For other stuff, e.g. create custom hook where I will get token from redux and make calls from it

*I also tried this two variants, but I could not decide which one better. And read few comments about this, but they were 50/50.*

Answer (score 2):

For me, i will say that it depends on which information that you want to share across your app. Here is my thought:

1. If your response is shared across the app, then putting them in the redux state is make sense, otherwise you no need to call via actions. If you put your API response to redux state, then it's good to normalize them first. (https://blog.brainsandbeards.com/advanced-redux-patterns-normalisation-6b9a5aa46e1f)
2. Having token in redux is okay, but soon you may consider to have a manager to manage the token instead of putting in Redux store because you will need addition action for token such as renewing new token and verification. With this approach, you can access the token anywhere.
3. You may create your own Request class to set default authentication for the APIs that need or do not need token

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i would minimize my use of Redux whenever possible. Not that its super convenient, but it adds a layer of unnecessary complexity.

Read Here : https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

I would go with the second option, you can still apply tokens from redux stores to your APIs.